# Bulk inserts with LINQ to SQL allowing some failures

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, bulkinsert

So, we have a service that takes list of updates via a WCF service, which should then be written to the DB. some of these could potentially fail (1000 updates/inserts per query) and if they do, the requirement is for the rest of the inserts/updates to be written, and the fails to be logged for processing later...

the question is how should this be done in LINQ to SQL. at the moment, i am doing something like follows:

```
        TestDataContext dc = new TestDataContext();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            Table table = new Table { randomNumber = r.Next(150) };
            dc.Tables.InsertOnSubmit(table);
        }
        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

in this example, Table.randomNumber is primary key. there should be duplicates in the dataset before getting written, but when i call dc.SubmitChanges() it throws an exception... instead of calling dc.SubmitChanges() after each iteration, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up submitting each row as they were written, and catching any errors. this way, i can catch the fails, but insert the rest correctly. Its not as slow as i though it would be, but not ideal... mind you, since this is a process that is done "offline" (backend processing) it works for what we need.